# clear() methods in Java

Tags: java, collections

Many of the container type data structures in Java come with a `clear()` method. For example, we can call `clear()` on a `Vector` we want to clear out all the contents in the `Vector`. My question is after applying the `clear()` method, does the content in the vector get nulled out or are they still being referenced? Thanks.

Comment: side question: how do so many people even HEAR about the Vector class? It never ceases to amaze me -- after all, it has been denigrated in favor of ArrayList for at least the last ten years!

Comment: I learned about the Vector class in java because I knew and used Vector's in languages like C++ before I learned java.

Comment: @Kevin Bourrillion: Some people hear about it because it's threadsafe in implementation, which ArrayList is definitely not.  Obviously you can wrap in synchronized objects, but for base data structures...

Comment: Oh, *yawn*.  If you have actual concurrent access going on, you're usually better off using a Queue or a CopyOnWriteArrayList anyway. Vector has nothing to recommend it. I guess it's just a matter of it having the expected name.

Comment: "Vector" sounds much cooler than "ArrayList".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They are no longer referenced by the Collection, but if you have any references anywhere in your code, that reference continues to exist as it was.

As mentioned, Vector's source does call:

```
// Let gc do its work
for (int i = 0; i < elementCount; i++)
    elementData[i] = null;
```

However, this is setting it's internal reference to null (pass-by-value) and will not affect any external references.

Answer (score 8):

They don't get nulled out --this makes no sense, it's only the reference which becomes null, not the value--, they simply get **dereferenced**. If they don't have any other reference on it (e.g. another class having it referenced as a static or instance variable), then they will be eligible for GC.

Comment: This is the best description of the implementation - the fact is that the collection never "had the objects" to begin with; it "had references" to the objects.

Answer (score 5):

If not referenced from elsewhere, they will be garbage collected.

Answer (score 3):

When it doubt, you can just take a look at the source code - it is bundled with the JDK (usually in a file named `rt.zip`).

```
public void clear() {
    removeAllElements();
}

public synchronized void removeAllElements() {
    modCount++;
    // Let gc do its work
    for (int i = 0; i < elementCount; i++)
        elementData[i] = null;

    elementCount = 0;
}
```

The "Let gc do its work" comment is from the actual source, not mine.

Answer (score 1):

```
//Let gc do its work
for (int i = 0; i < elementCount; i++) 
    elementData[i] = null;
```

This is the code, with the comment from the Vector class. It answers the question, I think.

Answer (score 0):

```
while(!stack.isEmpty()){
    System.out.println(stack.pop());
    System.out.println(stack);
}
```

Comment: Can you please add a short description about what you change/how it fixes the problem to your answer.

Comment: Code only answers are low quality and subject to deletion.  Every answer requires at least one or two sentences on what the writer expects the code snippet to do, and a high level intuition on what it does.